Examples of pure subobjects in the category of local rings
For an infinite regular cardinal $\kappa$, say a ring homomorphism $f : A \to B$ is $\kappa$-pure if, for every commutative diagram of ring homomorphisms,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A' @>{a}>> A \\
@V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
B' @>>{b}> B
\end{CD}$$
if $A'$ and $B'$ are $\kappa$-presentable (= admit a presentation with $< \kappa$ generators and $< \kappa$ relations), then there is a ring homomorphism $\bar{a} : B' \to A$ such that $\bar{a} \circ f' = a$.
(No compatibility required with $b$ or $f$.)
Let me paraphrase the above definition in language more familiar to model theorists.
For a commutative ring $A$, say a $\kappa$-presentable algebraic type of $A$ is a pair $(\vec{a}; E)$ where $\vec{a}$ is a tuple of elements of $A$ of length $\lambda < \kappa$ and $E$ is a set of $< \kappa$ pairs $(p, q)$ of polynomials in $\lambda$ variables with integer coefficients such that $p (\vec{a}) = q (\vec{a})$.
Then a ring homomorphism $f : A \to B$ is $\kappa$-pure iff, for every $\kappa$-presentable algebraic type $(\vec{a}; E)$ of $A$ and every $\kappa$-presentable algebraic type $(\vec{b}; F)$ of $B$ such that $f$ applied to each element of $\vec{a}$ is a prefix of $\vec{b}$ and $E \subseteq F$, there is an extension $\overline{a}$ of $\vec{a}$ such that $(\overline{a}, F)$ is a $\kappa$-presentable algebraic type of $A$.
In words, $f$ is $\kappa$-pure iff every $\kappa$-presentable algebraic type of $B$ over $f$ is realisable in $A$.
Clearly, any split monomorphism (i.e. inclusion of a retract) is $\kappa$-pure for all $\kappa$.
Every $\kappa$-pure homomorphism is injective: consider what happens when $A' = \mathbb{Z} [x_0, x_1]$, $B' = \mathbb{Z} [x]$, and $f' : A' \to B'$ is the unique ring homomorphism sending both $x_0$ and $x_1$ to $x$.
Thus we may focus on $\kappa$-pure subrings without loss of generality.
Question.
What are some examples of $\kappa$-pure subrings of commutative rings that are not retracts?
I am especially interested in examples of $\aleph_0$- and $\aleph_1$-pure subrings of local commutative rings.

It is clear that any $\kappa$-pure subring of $B$ is algebraically closed in $B$, but it is not clear to me whether purity is a stronger condition.
Since locality of a commutative ring can be stated as ($0 \ne 1$ and)
$$\forall x . ( \exists y . x y  = 1 ) \lor ( \exists y . (1 - x) y = 1 )$$
by considering $\mathbb{Z} [x] \to \mathbb{Z} [x, x^{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{Z} [x] \to \mathbb{Z} [x, (1 - x)^{-1}]$ we see that any $\aleph_0$-pure subring of a local commutative ring is local.
But what does this look like concretely?
